Set Env variable using Azure devops pipeline task PowershellOnTargetMachine failing
I am trying to set environment variable using azure devops pipeline task PowershellOnTargetMachine@3.
I am passing service account username and password. It is failing with error:

Computer must be trusted for delegation and current user account must be configured to allow delegation.

Really appreciate for the solution if anyone has seen this error before.
Environment variable set remotely.

Hi, could you share how your PowershellOnTargetMachine@3 task looks like? Is this machine AD-domain joined possibly?

According to this document PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3 - PowerShell on target machines v3 task | Microsoft Learn;

UPN formats such as username@domain.com and built-in system accounts such as NT Authority\System are not supported.

Please opt to use formats such as username, domain\username, machine-name\username, and .\username.

Thanks Alvin ! I am passing domain\username. Also it is service account.  do I need to do any setup on Azure devops side ?

Can you connect from local PowerShell to the remote machine with your domain account? I don't quite understand why this domain account is a user account as well as a service account. By the way would you consider authenticating against the local account of the target machine by remote-machine-name\LocalUserNameOnRemoteMachine. Either way, please make sure the domain\user or LocalAccount is able to connect to the remote machine from local machine first, then we can move on to integrate the workflow in a pipeline.

Thanks Alvin ! Yes I am able to connect to that server from powershell using Domain\username. Also, able to set variable using machin scope but for user scope it fails and givibg delegate error.  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Foo', '', 'Machine')  Thus works but [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Foo', '', User ) This fails.  Amy help is really appreciate

Hi @TejaswiniMahajan, Thanks for taking time to share the update. May I know whether the issue was reproducible, when you use Enter-PSSession -ComputerName to connect from the local machine to your remote machine with the domain user and ran the command [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Foo', '', 'User' )  or the error only occurred when running via pipeline? This is helpful to isolate the issue. Besides, can you please check if the sign-in domain user is a member of the Administrators group in your remote machine?

Hi Alvin
Yes the user is member of Administrators group.

$dataToProtect = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("test")
$scope = [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser
$protectedPasswordValue = $protectedDataClass::Protect($dataToProtect, $null, $scope)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestSecureString", "$test" , [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)

If I remove line no 2 for scope it is working.

Hi there, so may I assume the same script would also be failed without running it via pipeline? Can you please check if the command $scope = [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser is correct? It even failed with the error saying Unable to find type [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope], if I ran in local PowerShell prompt
